# Redirect from one tab to another tab

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I am using Easy responsive tabs and trying to redirect to another tab in the same modal.How can i achieve this using **jquery**.
Here is my code...

```
<div class="tab">
    <ul>
        <li class="resp-tab-item" aria-controls="tab_item-0" role="tab" ><span>LOGIN</span></li>
        <li class="resp-tab-item" aria-controls="tab_item-1" role="tab" ><span>REGISTRATION</span></li>                     
    </ul>
</div> 
<div class="tab-1 resp-tab-content" aria-labelledby="tab_item-0" id="tab1id">
    <div class="booking-form">
        <div class="online_reservation">
            <div class="b_room">
                <div class="booking_room"  >
                    <form  method="post" name="name" >        
                        <!-- TAB 1 CONTENTs -->
                        <div class="date_btn">                                        
                            <input type="submit" value="LOGIN" data-ng-click="submit()" >
                            <input type="submit" value="cancel" data-ng-click="cancel()" >
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="tab-2 resp-tab-content" aria-labelledby="tab_item-1" id="tab2id">
    <div class="booking-form">
        <div class="online_reservation">
            <div class="b_room">
                <div class="booking_room"  >
                    <form  method="post" name="name" >        
                        <!-- TAB 2 CONTENTs -->
                        <div class="date_btn">                                        
                            <input type="submit" value="LOGIN" data-ng-click="submit()" >
                            <input type="submit" value="cancel" data-ng-click="cancel()" >
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here, When i click on the **cancel** button from TAB1. I want to be redirected to  TAB2 contents.

Comment: It is far better you use jsFiddle. Easy responsive tabs at github structure is different with your format code.

Answer (score 1):

Have you write controller js for cancel()? If yes then use:

```
 $timeout(function () {
                    $('#status_tab').trigger('click');
                }, 100);
```

Here #status_tab is id of other tab.In your case take #tab2id.
Try it this works fine in my code.

Answer (score 0):

Current code:

```
<input type="submit" value="cancel" data-ng-click="cancel()" >
```

Replace with:

```
<a aria-controls="tab_item-1" role="tab">cancel</a>
```